# Plotting list of points as a checkerboard

Tags: plotting

I have a list of 2-tuples `list`. I would like to plot these tuples as colored-in squares like a checkerboard (except not checkered--the dark squares would only appear at the squares whose position correspond to some point in `list`.)

Additionally, I do *not* want the graph to have an overlayed grid.

The only way I know how to do something like this is with `ListPlot` by setting `PlotMarkers -> "\[FilledSquare]"`. But this seems to create problems with offset that make me wonder if there is a better aproach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{nrows, ncols} = {20, 30};
samplesize = 90;

list = RandomSample[Tuples@Range@{ncols, nrows}, samplesize];
```

#### ListPlot

You  can post-process `ListPlot` output to replace `Point`s with `Rectangle`s:

```
llp = ListPlot[list, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Medium]]]
```

[image]

```
Show[llp /. p_Point :> {{Black, Rectangle[# - 1/2] & /@ p[[1]]}, p}, 
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> {Range@30 - 1/2, Range@20 - 1/2}]
```

[image]

#### ArrayPlot

You can construct a `SparseArray` from `list` and use it with `ArrayPlot`:

```
data = SparseArray[Reverse /@ list -> 1, {nrows, ncols}];

ap = ArrayPlot[Reverse @ data, 
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
 Mesh -> All, 
 DataReversed -> False,
 DataRange -> {{1, 30}, {1, 20}}]
```

[image]

```
Show[ap, llp]
```

[image]

#### Graphics

Alternatively, you can construct `Rectangle` primitives from `list` and use `Graphics`:

```
gr = Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[# - 1/2] & /@ list}, Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> {Range[30] - 1/2, Range[20] - 1/2}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None];

Show[gr, llp]
```

[image]

#### BubbleChart

Append `1` to each pair in `list` and use the resulting data with `BubbleChart` with custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
bc = BubbleChart[Append[1] /@ list, AspectRatio -> 2/3, 
   GridLines -> {Range@30 - 1/2, Range@20 - 1/2}, 
   Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
   ChartElementFunction -> ({Black, Rectangle[Mean /@ # - 1/2]} &), 
   PlotRangePadding -> None];

Show[bc, llp]
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this generate a rotated version of the desired graph?

Comment: @DescartesBeforetheHorse, you are right. Updated with a fix.

Comment: For some reason, if you create a plot this way and export it as a PDF, it does not export the same graphic shown in Mathematica. The squares are replaced with bubbles.

Comment: @DescartesBeforetheHorse, if the issue arises for `ArrayPlot` only, it could be related to the issue covered in [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94817/125)

Comment: I tried what was in that post. Did not seem to work. It does not seem to be a rasterization issue--the squares don't become grainy after rasterization, the exported PDF has actual circles in place of squares.

Comment: @DescartesBeforetheHorse, interesting. Do you mind posting the issue as a new question with an example?

Comment: I was thinking of doing that. I will do so in the next day or two. Bit busy currently. Will use this post to generate an example.

Comment: @kglr: Is it because the directive is a circle so the pdf looks like a red circle in a square? If the circle is made a red square, wouldn't that solve the issue?

Comment: @Moo, I thought the issue was with the PDF export of  `ap` (without the red points) . For the PDF export of `Show[ap, llp]`  it is possible to have red points cover the black squares depending on the image size (because of the setting `PointSize[Medium]`)

Comment: @kglr: I may have misunderstood - excellent answer as usual - your answers are very uplifting and helpful!